# Capybara Poltergeist failing to load site inside vpn with StatusFailError

Tags: phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I'm trying to setup Poltergeist for headless testing in our company's CI system.

When I use Poltergeist on our internal servers, it looks like the remote site is closing the connection right away. Any idea why?

Google.com is fine and doing our tests with Chrome works too.

When the error happens, it happens right away (no long timeout). Here's the debug info below.

```
    {"id":"b29e0ebb-6fd3-4ac4-9699-133579c0bc5b","name":"set_debug","args":[true]}
2017-06-09T13:42:25 [DEBUG] CookieJar - Created but will not store cookies (use option '--cookies-file=<filename>' to enable persistent cookie storage)
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] Set  "http"  proxy to:  "" : 1080
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Configuration
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      0 objectName : ""
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      1 cookiesFile : ""
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      2 diskCacheEnabled : "false"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      3 maxDiskCacheSize : "-1"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      4 diskCachePath : ""
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      5 ignoreSslErrors : "true"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      6 localUrlAccessEnabled : "true"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      7 localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled : "false"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      8 outputEncoding : "UTF-8"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      9 proxyType : "http"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      10 proxy : ":1080"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      11 proxyAuth : ":"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      12 scriptEncoding : "UTF-8"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      13 webSecurityEnabled : "true"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      14 offlineStoragePath : ""
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      15 localStoragePath : ""
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      16 localStorageDefaultQuota : "-1"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      17 offlineStorageDefaultQuota : "-1"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      18 printDebugMessages : "true"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      19 javascriptCanOpenWindows : "true"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      20 javascriptCanCloseWindows : "true"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      21 sslProtocol : "tlsv1"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      22 sslCiphers : "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      23 sslCertificatesPath : ""
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      24 sslClientCertificateFile : ""
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      25 sslClientKeyFile : ""
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      26 sslClientKeyPassphrase : ""
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      27 webdriver : ":"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      28 webdriverLogFile : ""
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      29 webdriverLogLevel : "INFO"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      30 webdriverSeleniumGridHub : ""
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Script & Arguments
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      script: "/Users/gslzwol/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@cardinal/gems/poltergeist-1.13.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/main.js"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      0 arg: "53944"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      1 arg: "1024"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG]      2 arg: "768"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Starting normal mode
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/gslzwol/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@cardinal/gems/poltergeist-1.13.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/web_page.js"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/gslzwol/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@cardinal/gems/poltergeist-1.13.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/node.js"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/gslzwol/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@cardinal/gems/poltergeist-1.13.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/connection.js"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/gslzwol/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@cardinal/gems/poltergeist-1.13.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/cmd.js"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/gslzwol/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@cardinal/gems/poltergeist-1.13.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/browser.js"
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] WebpageCallbacks - getJsConfirmCallback
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] WebpageCallbacks - getJsConfirmCallback
{"command_id":"b29e0ebb-6fd3-4ac4-9699-133579c0bc5b","response":true}
{"id":"89134f88-b0bd-48ab-8ba2-bc518460754f","name":"visit","args":["https://internal.server?foo=bar"]}
2017-06-09T13:42:26 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
2017-06-09T13:42:28 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(RemoteHostClosedError) ( "Connection closed" ) URL: "https://internal.server/?foo=bar"
2017-06-09T13:42:28 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100
2017-06-09T13:42:28 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-06-09T13:42:28 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-06-09T13:42:28 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript "(function() { return (function () {\n      return typeof __poltergeist;\n    })(); })()"
2017-06-09T13:42:28 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(QString, "undefined")
{"command_id":"89134f88-b0bd-48ab-8ba2-bc518460754f","error":{"name":"Poltergeist.StatusFailError","args":["https://internal.server?foo-bar",null]}}
```

Here's my browser setup:

```
 when 'poltergeist'
      Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
        options = { 
          :debug => true,
          :phantomjs_options => [
            '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes',
            '--debug=true',
          ]
        } 
        Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
      end
      Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
```

Poltergeist 1.13.0, Capybara 2.6.2, Ruby 2.1.7-p400, OSX 10.11.6 . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This block of code fixed the issue. I suspect it's an SSL security problem and the ssl-protocol=any option fixed it.

I'm going to use this for all my bugs from now on :)

```
    phantomjs_options: [
      '--proxy-type=none', 
      '--load-images=no', 
      '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', 
      '--ssl-protocol=any',
      '--web-security=false',
      '--debug=true
    ]
```